# How to initialize a "bad" empty reference to abstract class

Tags: c++, templates, reference

I'll get straight to it: I have a class template that holds a reference and updates info to it:

```
template<class T>
class Parser {
    T& m_ref;
public:
    typedef T ValueType;
    Parser(T& ref): m_ref(ref) {}
    virtual void read(std::istream&);
};
```

Now, I have another template that creates a new object and updates it using this interface, to do so I have a field that saves the parser.
However, I'd like to use updater to classes that derive from T, which is impossible with poymorphism since `Parser<Derived>` does not inherit from `Parser<Base>`.
I created this work-around that uses an intermediate class that inherits from `Parser<Base>` but updates into a `Parser<Derived>`:

```
template<class T>
struct dummy {};
template<class T>
class Creator {
    typedef shared_ptr<Parser<T> > ParserPtr;
    typedef shared_ptr<T> ValuePtr;

    ValuePtr m_output;
    ParserPtr m_parser;

    template<class ParserType>
    class LocalParser : public Parser<T> {
        ParserType m_parser;
    public:
        LocalParser(typename ParserType::ValueType& val):
            Parser<T>(/*???*/), //problems start here, I must initialize the base
            m_parser(val) {}
        void read(std::istream& is) { //use polymorphism to update into some derieved reference
            m_parser.read(is);
        }
    };
public:
    Creator(): //Uses Parser<T> as default parser
        m_output(new T), 
        m_parser(new Parser<T>(*m_output)) {}
    template<class ParserType>
    Creator(dummy<ParserType>) { //Use any parser
        auto temp = make_shared(new typename ParserType::ValueType);
        m_output = temp;
        m_parser = maked_shared(new LocalParser<ParserType>(*temp));
    }
    virtual ValuePtr read()(std::istream& is) {
        m_parser->read(is);
        return m_output;
    }
};
```

Basically `LocalParser` is an intermediate class that inherits from `Parser<T>` but updates a diffrent reference from the one it's base holds.
The problem here is how to initialize `Parser<T>`, especially when `T` is abstract (which is 99% of the time I actually use this class with a derived parser).

My question boils down to "how to define a reference to a (possibly) abstract class that WON'T be used?" (or is there any kind of other work around where I don't define an intermidiate that inherits from `Parser<T>`).

**EDIT**: The Parser interface is a separate code I cannot change.

Comment: why does it have to be a reference instead of a pointer?

Comment: Can you create a **minimal**, **complete** example? There's lots of types in this question, most of which are irrelevant to what you're asking.

Comment: It's derive, derived.

Comment: @Barry The question is: Is there any way to create an empty reference to a general class (that can be abstracrt, so a reference to a temporary object is not a solution)?
The rest of the description is the reason I would wan't to do this wierd thing, so people could suggest other solutions that won't require this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create an empty reference. A reference **must** refer to something. That's one of the key differences between a reference and a pointer. In fact, there's a possible solution for you:

```
T& ref;           // error
T& ref = nullref; // no such thing

T* ptr = nullptr; // "empty" pointer!
```

Another possibly more explicit solution that allows for either a reference or nothing would be to use [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html):

```
boost::optional<T&> opt_ref; // empty optional
opt_ref = some_t;
```